# dynamic textbox in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
 string str = string.Empty;

 foreach (ListItem item in this.CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
       if (item.Selected)
           {
              str += item.Value + "<br><br>";
              TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();

           }
    }

 lbl1.Text = str;
```

What I want is for each data checked I want to have a textbox. When I loop through the checkbox List the label takes my values and display them but the textbox not. How can I do it?

Comment: which kind of app is it? WinForms? ASP.NET? Also, you create a textbox object but you don't add it to any container, you don't specify a location in any way.

Comment: Where is "the" TextBox? You create a new TextBox object in the loop for every selected entry, but you never asign anything to it and you never place it in the form or any onther container object. What did you expect?

Comment: @mesiesta its a asp.net. [`CheckBoxList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) is a `webcontrol`

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (ListItem item in this.CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
       if (item.Selected)
           {
              str += item.Value + "<br><br>";
              TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
              //name of your form should go here
               form1.Controls.add(txt1); 
               //plus you have to figure it out how to position textboxes on the page
           }
    }
```